# Helicopter with Mary on board/onboard/aboard

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> The helicopter with Mary on board/onboard/aboard took off.

I have seen all three used. Are they all correct?

Examples taken from Google:

*Military helicopter with 3 on board goes missing in Vietnam*

*Army helicopter with 8 onboard makes emergency landing*

*A firefighting helicopter with seven people aboard crashed Friday*

Answer (score 2):

"On board" is correct.  "Onboard" is non-standard in that position (but a common error)
"Aboard" is widely used in this position.

We use "onboard" as an adjective that describes something as being or happening on a boat.

> The cruise liner has an onboard swimming pool.

("Onboard" is also used as a verb, but that sounds like horrible business cant)

We tend to use "aboard" as an adverb referring to the act of moving onto a boat

> Please step aboard the ship.

But it is quite common to use aboard and "on board" in your context

> THere are 10 people on board / 10 people aboard.

With no real difference in meaning.